Python in excel does not have the side buttons
I added python in Excel and I am trying to figure it out how it works. In microsoft's official website it has side menu but my add-in does not show it.enter image description here
If you check microsoft, it has 3 buttons : "reset,diagnostics,initialization"
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-started-with-python-in-excel-a33fbcbe-065b-41d3-82cf-23d05397f53d#:~:text=To%20begin%20using%20Python%20in,a%20cell%20to%20enable%20Python.
How can i get them?
thanks
I tried to remove and add it back, it did not work, excel is updated too.

Exactly how did you add it? It should be part of the current Office 365 and then you can find it in the Formula-menu. I don't know if it works in the online version.

Which version of Office do you have? This feature is only available to Microsoft 365 subscriptions. And only available in Excel for Windows.

If you're in a corporate environment it may also be disabled or blocked due to security concerns (bugger)

It is business laptop but I have all the access. I can run python,sql or vba easily and set up any software I need. No limitations to me. I have windows 10 and MS 365 for business. I could not get it from formulas tab, I went to "Customize Ribbon" and found "Insert Python" in functions and that is how I added it to my excel.

Maybe try the Reset button toward the bottom right corner of the "Customize Ribbon" screen.
